# Nginx Reverse Proxy do not load JS and CSS from other server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two versions of an Angular WebApp running on two different servers (prod and dev). The prod version is on exemple.com and the dev version is on exemple.com/dev. However, when I set the proxy to load the dev version, only the index.html file is loaded, JS and CSS are not loaded. When I check the request url in devtools, I see that index.html comes from https://exemple.com/dev while main.bundle.js comes from https://exemple.com/.

Here is the nginx.conf for the prod server:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /site/app;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        }

        location /dev {
                proxy_pass http://10.10.38.18/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

And here for the dev server:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /site/webApp;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                autoindex on;
        }
        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, by default angular apps have a `<base href="/">` tag that says to the browser to get relative urls from `/` (https://example.com/).

You need to either change the `href="/"` to `href="/dev/"` or you can replace it directly with nginx with the [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module.

An other solution (maybe the best one) would be to serve the dev app from a subdomain like dev.example.com, you would need to set your DNS to make dev.example.com point to example.com and define two nginx servers:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.example.com;
  ...
}
```